# How to pass Livenet Txhash on a testnet Bitcore node

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcore

I want to pass Txhash of a livenet Bitcoin transaction to a service created in Testnet bitcoin node.
I have been using Bitcore as my client for writing services in nodejs.
[This is my Bitcoin Client](http://www.bitcore.io)

Comment: I don't understand this question at all.  What do you mean by "pass", and what does it mean that your service was "created in" a Testnet node?  Can you please edit your question and explain in a lot more detail what you are trying to do and how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is the information you're asking for, but Testnet uses a different address format and derives from its own genesis block, therefore all content from the mainnet's blockchain is incompatible with testnet. Mainnet transactions are incompatible with testnet.